# Any method use Import and Export in CloudDeploy?

Tags: cloud-deploy

I have a test file(`test1.txt`) in my desktop.This is its content.

```
FilePrint[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test1.txt"}]]
(*
31.16   220.49774362741593
31.18   223.49849688143496
31.2    226.49924900492292
31.22   223.5
31.24   228.5
31.26   231.5
31.28   227.5
31.3    222.5
31.32   222.5
35.72   209.72984917230133
35.74   220.68588083509488
*)
```

I try to use `Import` and `Export` in `CloudDeploy`.

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage["fileAddress" -> 
   "String", (data = Import[#fileAddress, "Table"]; Sin[data]; 
    Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.txt"}], 
     data]) &], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Of course this action will get a error.But I have to say this two function can help a lot in real life.So any method or workaround can do this?

---

#### Aim:

I want to create some `CloudObject`  which have some specific function to help my friends who have no `mma`.I hope she upload `test1.txt`,then get `test.txt`in her local disk.Just by her browser.

Comment: Is something like  this what you're looking for? It gives you an uploader which you can select from a file browser or click&drag into: `CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"data" -> "CSV"}, Print[#data] &]]`

Comment: note the 2nd argument isn't going to work, I just wanted to demonstrate the FormFunction upload page you'll see initially.

Comment: @user6014 Wow,I have to say this is a wonderful comment.I think.it can replace that `Import` in my case.BTW,have you summarize other format also can realize such similar function except `"CSV"`.Would you put [your comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127248/any-method-use-import-and-export-in-clouddeploy#comment344199_127248) as a answer?I think it give very useful information to my question.And any workaround for `Export`?

Comment: I submitted an answer which hopefully helps for half the question, in regards to Export I think it's possible but I don't have time to look into it at the moment.

Comment: @Kuba The problem of uploading files is seem to be solved by [user6014](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34161/user6014).The remaining problem is how to put a result file into my local disk.

Comment: @Kuba I have made a updation just now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think you can automatically save to someone's file system but you can create a download link, it is up to the user to click and get it:

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[
  {"first" -> "Number", "second" -> "Number"}, 
  Module[{f = CreateFile[]},
    StringTemplate[
      "<a href=\"``\" download>Click here to save test.txt</a>"
    ][
       URLShorten @@ CloudExport[#second + #first, "Text", "test.txt", 
         Permissions -> "Public"]
    ]
  ] &
 ],
 Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

This is an example with two numbers input but you can easily use user6014's suggestion for files uploading

```
{"data" -> "CSV"}
```

and process them however you want.

Comment: I will learn some knowledge of cloud then comment this answer.Thanks. :)

Comment: @yode Sure, let me know how does it work for you or if you need something more.

Comment: Not need something more.I just don't very like that link.The network is little weak in China.When I click the link,the browse sometime will give a hint that I cannot access it.So I look forward a file directly still.Well,I think the `URLDownload` can help.I will give a try for this tomorrow.

Comment: `CloudDeploy[FormPage["file"->"Table",(URLDownload[Sequence@@CloudExport[Sin[#file],"Table",Permissions->"Public"],FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory,"Desktop","test.txt"}]])&],"testFile",Permissions->"Public"]` is what I think.It seem browser cannot do such thing.

Comment: Little blemish,when I change it into `CloudExport[Sin[#file], "Table", "test.txt", Permissions -> "Public"]`.I cannot get a real table file like `Export`.Actually the file is a table format.

Comment: @yode I will respond in 24h, i am travelling now.

Comment: Ok.Great day! :)

Comment: @yode Your code works, but not how you think it should. `URLDownload` is executed by the Cloud so it tries to download your CloudExported result to Cloud's Desktop directory. FormFunctions/Pages functions are executed on CLoud side and cloud can't have access to users desktop.

Comment: Do you mean we have no method access to local desktop?And how about the "Table" format?

Comment: I have tried some methods these days,but I think maybe the browser never cannot write the local disk.

Comment: @yode sure it can;t do that automatically, would you like it  to be able do put malicious scripts just because you've opened a page?

Answer (score 5):

FormFunction allows you to upload files directly into the browser, which should bypass your need for Import. If your typespec for your FormFunction is something which Mathematica knows is a file type then it will prompt you to upload a file in the deployed page:

`CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"data" -> "CSV"}, ...`

[image: Cloud data import]

I believe any of the form specifications for Interpreter are valid typespecs in FormFunction (details and options):

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html

Comment: This help me a lot,thanks. :)

Comment: I realize the new function `URLDownload` maybe can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have to declare that this answer is just combination with [user6014's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127269/21532) and [Kuba's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127514/21532).I compose this for reading.I find the "Table" format maybe have some bug,which don't same to `Export[*,"Table"]`.So I make a workaround by `XLS` for this target.

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage["file" -> "Table", 
  StringTemplate[
     "Click <a href=\"``\" download>here</a> to save as test.xls"][
    Sequence @@ 
     CloudExport[Sin[#file], "XLS", "test.xls", 
      Permissions -> "Public"]] &], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

You can use my `test1.txt` to test this cloud object.If anyone can give a method just using browser to save a file in local disk,I'd glad to kow still.